# Why is the AddMultiplicationEquality limited to only 2 variables?

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I am building a shift scheduler with a complex set of constraints, and I am using CP-SAT solver for this. I have an array like this:

```
    num_vals = 3
    for n in all_employees:
        for d in all_timeslots:
            shifts[(n, d)] = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, 'shift_n%id%i' % (n, d))
```

am trying to setup a constraint where a product of consequent line of 5 IntVar values always equals to zero, so I am using something like this:

```
        sq_r = model.NewIntVar(0, 1,'sq_r')
        for wind in range(0,11):
            model.AddMultiplicationEquality(sq_r, [shifts[(n, wind)], shifts[(n, wind+1)], shifts[(n, wind+2)], shifts[(n, wind+3)], shifts[(n, wind+4)]])
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Check failed: vars.size() == 2 (5 vs. 2) General int_prod not supported yet.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @   00007FF98D2B8C45  PyInit__pywrapsat
    @   00007FF98D2B6F82  PyInit__pywrapsat
    @   00007FF98D550E50  PyInit__pywrapsat
    @   00007FF98D54D8FF  PyInit__pywrapsat
....
```

I already checked the documentation on http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html and also some examples here and on github, but never found any example where more than 2 items are found in the variables list, although the docs are showing the following:

```
def AddMultiplicationEquality(self, target, variables)
Adds target == variables[0] * .. * variables[n]
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Like it says, it's not implemented *yet*. I guess they had planned to be more general and put it in the documentation, but never got around to doing it.

Comment: Exactly, I have never found one use case for it, and yours in not an exception.  In your case, prod == 0 is equivalent to one var is == 0. You can have one boolean variable for each var equivalent to var == 0, and add a bool_or on those boolean variables. It will be much more efficient that a multiplication of 5 variables. See https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md.

Comment: This is implemented in CP-SAT from OR-Tools 9.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
num_vals = 3
for n in all_employees:
    for d in all_timeslots:
        shifts[(n, d)] = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, 'shift_n%id%i' % (n, d))
        shifts_is_zero[(n, d)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_is_zero_n%id%i' % (n, d))
        model.Add(shifts[(n, d)] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(shifts_is_zero[(n, d)])
        model.Add(shifts[(n, d)] > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(shifts_is_zero[(n, d)].Not())
```

then

```
    for wind in range(0,11):
        model.AddBoolOr([shifts_is_zero[(n, wind)], shifts_is_zero[(n, wind+1)], shifts_is_zero[(n, wind+2)], shifts_is_zero[(n, wind+3)], shifts_is_zero[(n, wind+4)]])
```